# How to Sort CIDR portion of Results that includes test in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, string, sorting, ip-address, cidr

I have a query in Python 2.7.  All works without issues; however, I have a need to have the results sorted based on Network CIDR.  Below is the code and a copy of results that I am getting along what the results I have been trying to get.  Tried all types of sorting and can't seem to get any sorting to actually work.

```
query = """
    SELECT Address,
        CIDR, FriendlyName
    FROM IPAM.GroupNode
    """
    results = swis.query(query)
    for row in results['results']:
        print("{FriendlyName} is using CIDR - Address}/{CIDR}".format(**row))
```

Returns The Results Below:

```
Some Customer is using CIDR - 10.200.104.0/22
Some Others is using CIDR - 10.200.86.0/22
Customer1 in CO is using CIDR - 10.200.0.0/20
Customer2 is using CIDR - 10.200.64.0/20
Another Cust is using CIDR - 10.200.32.0/22
Another Cust2 is using CIDR - 10.200.128.0/20
Another Cust3 is using CIDR - 10.200.112.0/22
```

What I need to do is have it instead return something like:

```
Customer1 in CO is using CIDR - 10.200.0.0/20
Another Cust is using CIDR - 10.200.32.0/22
Customer2 is using CIDR - 10.200.64.0/20
Some Others is using CIDR - 10.200.86.0/22
Some Customer is using CIDR - 10.200.104.0/22
Another Cust3 is using CIDR - 10.200.112.0/22
Another Cust2 is using CIDR - 10.200.128.0/20
```

Comment: I'm thinking you could probably put all of these in a list, and sort the list using a `key= lambda` parameter

Answer (score 0):

Make a list before your `for` loop:

```
cidrs = []
```

Replace `print` with `.append()`:

```
cidrs.append("{FriendlyName} is using CIDR - Address}/{CIDR}".format(**row))
```

Sort the list by CDIR block (aka, Last two digits):

```
sorted(cidrs, key=lambda x: x[-2:])
```